# confusion on understanding this plotting function in R

Tags: r

When studying the linear modeling, I once read the following R script used for plotting:

```
plot(d[, 2], d[, 4], xlab="d[, 2]", ylab="d[, 4]", col=2 * (1 + (d[, 1] == "A")))
```

Here d is a data set. what confuses me is how to understand what does `col=2 * (1 + (d[, 1] == "A"))` aim to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Effectively, it is setting the color (`col`) of the points based on the value of the first column (`d[,1]`). The specific mapping between the values can be gotten by working out the possibilities:

`d[,1]=="A"` is `TRUE` if the first column is "A", `FALSE` otherwise.

`1+(d[,1]=="A")` takes this TRUE/FALSE value and converts it to a number (1 and 0, respectively), so that it can be added to the number 1. So it is `2` if the first column is "A", and `1` otherwise.

`2*(1+(d[,1]=="A"))` just multiplies those numbers by 2, so it is `4` if the first column is "A" and `2` otherwise.

The net effect is that point that corresponds to rows where the first column is "A" are drawn in color `4` and all other points are drawn in color `2`.

To determine what colors these numbers refer to, they are indices into the results of `palette()`.

```
> palette()[4]
[1] "blue"
> palette()[2]
[1] "red"
```

So points which the first column is "A" are in blue, others are in red.

Comment: Maybe also worth mentioning that integers supplied to `col` are used to index elements of the vector returned by `palette()` (which contains a set of default colors, but can be reset by the user).

Comment: @JoshO'Brien Good idea. I've added that to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm late with my answer, but it may still be helpful to someone...

The parameter `col` determines the colors of points on the plot.

```
# Create some data to plot.
x=1:5
y=x^2
group = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C")

group == "A" # Outputs a logical vector.
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE

2 * (1 + (group == "A")) # Changes logical vector to integers.
# [1] 4 4 2 2 2

# col parameter interprets integers as colors for each point in the plot.
plot(x, y, col=2 * (1 + (group == "A")), pch=20, cex=3)
```

[image]